# SQL: Update table when the table copying from has duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains unique names, call it table1. I have another table which contains the same names but each name occurs several times, call it table2. Now, I want to copy data from table2 to table1 corresponding to the names. And if table2 has multiple records by the same name, I want the corresponding new records to be created in table1.

```
TABLE1                    TABLE2
NAME                       NAME
A                           A
B                           A
C                           B
D                           B
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? That should not be too difficult to solve...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @NicoHaase can you tell me how to achieve this. I am fairly new to sql

Comment: @NicoHaase I just got an idea of trying left join. I will try it and keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: If your lost on what to look into, look into "WHERE NOT EXISTS". Although you could use "LEFT JOIN" as you stated above.

Comment: @Monofuse but I am using UPDATE statement on table1, and it is only keeping the same number of records in table1 and not increasing it

Comment: Sorry my bad. If you create a select query which finds all the data you require e.g. left join and then a is null in the where statement. Then replace the select segment of the select query with an update (don't but the table name here, but use the as name you placed in the from segment of the query). This will allow you to update the found values from the original select statement.

Comment: If you could post something you've tried, I'd be more than willing to then post an answer with something you could use.

Comment: update TT
  set 
  TT.exp=tmp.exp,
  tt.Project_type=tmp.prj_type,
  tt.rscpool_name=tmp.rscpool
  from test TT
  right join #temp12 tmp
  on tmp.user_name=TT.user_name
   drop table #temp12
   select * from test

Comment: @Monofuse here temp12 is table2

Answer (score 0):

Following the little chat int he comments, you could try this:

```
UPDATE t1
set columnx = t2.columnx
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name is null
```

To achieve your full requirements, you may find it more useful to have multiple queries accomplish the one task.

Comment: how does keeping t2.name = null help?